# Como remover linhas de uma tabela A que não possui relacionamento com a tabela B?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho 2 tabelas e quero remover as linhas da tabela A que não possui relacionamento com a tabela B?

Por exemplo: Na tabela B eu tenho um campo FK_ID e quero remover da tabela A todos as linhas que não tem relacionamento com a tabela B, ou seja, que não possui um A.FK_ID = B.FK_ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa é uma maneira de fazer:

```
DELETE FROM TABELA_A where TABELA_A.FK_ID not in (select FK_ID FROM TABELA_B)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Usando `NOT EXISTS`**

```
DELETE t_a
  FROM a t_a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM b t_b
                   WHERE t_b.fk_id = t_a.fk_id)
```

**Usando `JOIN`**

```
DELETE t_a
  FROM a t_a
  LEFT JOIN b t_b ON t_b.fk_id = t_a.fk_id
 WHERE b.fk_id IS NULL
```